# NGINX is not able to show some pages from 3rd party applications

Tags: nginx, openssl, nginx-reverse-proxy, openresty, qradar

I am using NGINX(Openresty) to host 3rd party application (IBM QRadar) with server block and proxy_pass to the running application in tomcat, Everything is working fine but some pages are not loading.
Those pages are add-on plugins in the QRadar platform. No any errors showing at NGINX logs or QRadar tomcat.
This is happening only when access through NGINX. Direct access with the localhost works perfect.
It was working with old openresty version - 1.11.2.3

Not working on
NGINX version: openresty/1.21.4.1

- Tried to remove all CSP headers
- Reinstalled openresty

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.